# ScrollView embedded in TableLayout embedded in RelativeLayout with ListView outside Not Working

Tags: android, listview, scrollview, tablelayout

Before I added my ListView, along with changing my TableLayout height to "wrap_content" as opposed to "fill_parent", my ScrollView displayed properly.  Here is my XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
 <TableLayout android:id="@+id/details"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
  android:stretchColumns="1">
  <TableRow>
   <TextView android:text="Restaurant Name: " />
   <EditText android:id="@+id/name" />
  </TableRow>
  <TableRow>
   <TextView android:text="Address: " />
   <EditText android:id="@+id/addr" />
  </TableRow>
  <TableRow>
   <TextView android:text="Type:" />
   <ScrollView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
   <RadioGroup android:id="@+id/types"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/fastfood"
     android:text="Fast-Food" />
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/family"
     android:text="Family" />
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/casual_dining"
     android:text="Casual Dining" />
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/fine_dining"
     android:text="Fine Dining" />
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/cafe"
     android:text="Cafe" />
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/cafeteria"
     android:text="Cafeteria" />
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/coffeehouse"
     android:text="Coffeehouse" />
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/pub"
     android:text="Pub" />
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/greasy_spoon"
     android:text="Greasy Spoon" />
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/chain"
     android:text="Chain" />
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/truck_stop"
     android:text="Truck Stop" />
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/smorgasbord"
     android:text="Smorgasbord" />
   </RadioGroup>
   </ScrollView>
  </TableRow>
  <TableRow>
   <TextView android:text="" />
   <Button android:id="@+id/save"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Save" />
  </TableRow>
 </TableLayout>
 <ListView android:id="@+id/restaurants"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
  android:layout_above="@id/details" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I get no ScrollView when I have "wrap_content" and my display is askew!  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually did some experimenting with different values in the height.  When I provide a specific height, the total display is how it should be.  I simply added a specific value to my TableLayout height and my ScrollView height and all is well.

I am not sure why this is so, but it works.  If anyone wishes to explain the logic...feel free! :)